# How to Add a Space in Line Numbers in Textarea Word Wrap in Svelte

Tags: css, textarea, svelte

I have a text area with CSS generated line numbers for each new line.

[image: Word Wrap CSS]

Everything works great, except for when there is a word wrap. If I get a word wrap, it does not wrap the new line text. I would like to make my line numbers word wrap with the text.

Here is a notepad+ example:

[image: notepad+ word wrap]

And here is a GitHub example:

[image: GitHub word wrap]

How can I automatically detect and add a word wrap to my line numbers as well? Here is my code:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    export let source = `jon
sup
me
fixin to do sumthin good`;

    let numberOfLines = source.split('\n').length;

    const KeyUp = (event: Event) => {
        const textarea = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
        numberOfLines = textarea.value.split('\n').length;
    };

    const KeyDown = (event: Event) => {
        const textarea = event.target as HTMLInputElement;

        if ((event as KeyboardEvent).key === 'Tab') {
            const start = textarea.selectionStart;
            const end = textarea.selectionEnd;

            if (start && end) {
                textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0, start) + '\t'
                + textarea.value.substring(end);
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    };
</script>

<center>
    <div class="editor">
        <div class="line-numbers">
            {#each Array(numberOfLines) as _}
                <span class="new-line" />
            {/each}
        </div>
        <textarea class="text-content" 
        on:keyup={KeyUp} on:keydown={KeyDown} value={source} rows="15" />
    </div>
</center>

<style>
    .editor {
        display: inline-flex;
        gap: 10px;
        font-family: monospace;
        line-height: 21px;
        background: #282a3a;
        border-radius: 2px;
        padding: 20px 10px;
    }

    .line-numbers {
        width: 20px;
        text-align: right;
    }

    .line-numbers .new-line {
        counter-increment: linenumber;
    }

    .line-numbers .new-line::before {
        content: counter(linenumber);
        display: block;
        color: #506882 !important;
    }

    .text-content {
        line-height: 21px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        background: #282a3a;
        color: #fff;
        min-width: 500px;
        outline: none;
        resize: none;
    }
</style>
```

And here is the StackBlitz Link:

[image: Open in StackBlitz]

(right click - open in new window)

Thanks!

J

---

Image for responding to comment below:

[image: No Lines]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach could be to read the width of one character of the monospace font from an invisible element and set the textarea width to a multiple to avoid rounding errors. It then can be calculated for each substring between the line breaks how often it is wrapped and a margin-bottom added to the corresponding line number accordingly

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/fd528542bc7b4e219a4c9d84bf82bb11?version=3.55.0)

```
<script>
    import {onMount} from 'svelte'

    export let source = `jon\nsup there is some other text here that I want to go across the lines and not word wrap another line etc boy!\nme\nfixin to do sumthin good`;

    let fontWidthElem
    let fontWidth
    let charactersPerLine = 60
    $: areaWidth = charactersPerLine * fontWidth

    onMount(() => {
        fontWidth = fontWidthElem.getBoundingClientRect().width
    })

    function wrapped(str, timesWrapped) {
        if(str.length > charactersPerLine) {
            const firstLine = str.substring(0, charactersPerLine)
            const spaceOrDashInFirstLine = /[ -]/.test(firstLine)
            const lastCharFirstLine = str[charactersPerLine-1]
            const firstCharNextLine = str[charactersPerLine]
            const wordIsCut = lastCharFirstLine !== '-' && lastCharFirstLine !== ' ' && firstCharNextLine !== ' ' && firstCharNextLine !== '-'
            const nextLine = str.substring(charactersPerLine)
            const nextLineNotOnlySpaces = nextLine.replaceAll(' ', '').length > 0
            if(wordIsCut && spaceOrDashInFirstLine){
                const lastIndexOfDivider = Math.max(firstLine.lastIndexOf(' '), firstLine.lastIndexOf('-'))
                return wrapped(str.substring(lastIndexOfDivider+1), timesWrapped+1)
            }else if(nextLineNotOnlySpaces){
                return wrapped(nextLine.trimStart(), timesWrapped+1)
            }else {
                return timesWrapped             
            }
        }else {
            return timesWrapped
        }
    }

</script>

<div class="editor">

    <div class="line-numbers">
        {#each source.split('\n') as subStr, index}
        <div class="line-nr"
                 style:margin-bottom="calc(var(--line-height) * {wrapped(subStr, 0)})"
                 >
            {index + 1}
        </div>
        {/each}
    </div>

    <textarea bind:value={source}
                        style:width="{areaWidth}px"
                        rows="15" 
                        />

    <div id="font-width"
             bind:this={fontWidthElem}           
             >
        a
    </div>

</div>

<style>
    :global(body) {
        padding: 0;
    }

    .editor {
        --line-height: 21px;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-flex;       
        gap: 10px;
        padding: 20px 10px;
        font-family: monospace;
        line-height: var(--line-height);
        background: #282a3a;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }

    .line-nr {
        width: 20px;
        text-align: right;
        color: #506882 !important;
    }

    textarea {
        line-height: var(--line-height);
        overflow-y: hidden;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        background: #282a3a;
        color: #fff;
        outline: none;
        resize: none;
    }

    #font-width {
        position: absolute;
        top: -1000px;
        left: -1000px;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

To make the width responsive

- additional editor wrapper for padding
- watch editor width and calculate maximal possible `charactersPerLine` for textarea besides line numbers element
- `charactersPerLine` added as argument to `wrapped()` for recalculation on change

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/18a44e9ac58b46faa1f1d60f0810dc93?version=3.55.0)

```
<script>
    import {onMount} from 'svelte'

    export let source = `jon\nsup there is some other text here that I want to go across the lines and not word wrap another line etc boy!\nme\nfixin to do sumthin good`;

    let fontWidthElem
    let fontWidth
    let editorWidth

    onMount(() => {
        fontWidth = fontWidthElem.getBoundingClientRect().width
    })

    let lineNumbersWidth = 30
    $: charactersPerLine = Math.floor((editorWidth - lineNumbersWidth) / fontWidth)

    function wrapped(str, charactersPerLine, timesWrapped) {
        if(str.length > charactersPerLine) {
            const firstLine = str.substring(0, charactersPerLine)
            const spaceOrDashInFirstLine = /[ -]/.test(firstLine)
            const lastCharFirstLine = str[charactersPerLine-1]
            const firstCharNextLine = str[charactersPerLine]
            const wordIsCut = lastCharFirstLine !== '-' && lastCharFirstLine !== ' ' && firstCharNextLine !== ' ' && firstCharNextLine !== '-'
            const nextLine = str.substring(charactersPerLine)
            const nextLineNotOnlySpaces = nextLine.replaceAll(' ', '').length > 0
            if(wordIsCut && spaceOrDashInFirstLine){
                const lastIndexOfDivider = Math.max(firstLine.lastIndexOf(' '), firstLine.lastIndexOf('-'))
                return wrapped(str.substring(lastIndexOfDivider+1), charactersPerLine, timesWrapped+1)
            }else if(nextLineNotOnlySpaces){
                return wrapped(nextLine.trimStart(), charactersPerLine, timesWrapped+1)
            }else {
                return timesWrapped             
            }
        }else {
            return timesWrapped
        }
    }

</script>

<div class="editor-wrapper">

    <div class="editor"
             bind:clientWidth={editorWidth}
             >

        <div class="line-numbers"
                 style:width="{lineNumbersWidth}px"
                 >
            {#each source.split('\n') as subStr, index}
            <div class="line-nr"
                     style:margin-bottom="calc(var(--line-height) * {wrapped(subStr, charactersPerLine, 0)})"
                     >
                {index + 1}
            </div>
            {/each}
        </div>

        <textarea bind:value={source}
                            style:width="{charactersPerLine}ch"
                            rows="15" 
                            />

        <div id="font-width"
                 bind:this={fontWidthElem}           
                 >
            a
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<style>
    :global(body) {
        padding: 0;
    }
    :global(*) {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .editor-wrapper {
        --line-height: 21px;
        padding: 20px 10px;
        background: #282a3a;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }

    .editor {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        font-family: monospace;
        line-height: var(--line-height);
    }

    .line-numbers {
        padding-right: 10px;
        text-align: right;
        color: #506882 !important;
    }

    textarea {
        line-height: var(--line-height);
        overflow-y: hidden;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        background: #282a3a;
        color: #fff;
        outline: none;
        resize: none;
/*      border seems to falsify calculation! */
/*      box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px grey; */
    }

    #font-width {
        position: absolute;
        top: -1000px;
        left: -1000px;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Almost! It does not seem to work for multiple lines, and sometimes doesn't work on second line. Hold down one letter and press enter to see the problem.

Comment: @Jonathan Which system/browser?

Comment: Chrome, but I tested this on multiple browsers. I added the example problems in an image to the original question above.

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks for the image. This special case where there's no whitespace in the first line was not yet considered. Added it and updated the Repl

Comment: Ok looks great! Is there a way to make the textarea 100% of the container it is in?

Comment: @Jonathan I added a responsive version

Comment: @Corri - I found a bug if you don't mind looking at it - https://svelte.dev/repl/a5fdf85404b5442c9a3ad0e1918b108c?version=3.55.0

Comment: @Jonathan Here's the thing that a dash might also cause a wrap. With the trim I meant to cover that whitespaces at the end of a line won't cause a wrap, but that also wasn't explicit enough. I adjusted the logic once more. (Notice that special whitespaces like hair- or thinspace aren't handled and might cause unexpected results)